# How can print the full row where a specific string is found in a text file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm searching for a string in a text file and trying to printing it out. The output I get is all in one line and I don't know how to separate it so that it is on multiple lines.

My text file contains the following

```
Number      Date    Time
08-D-123519 02-Apr-2016 21:58:54
05-WD-3052  02-Apr-2016 22:03:350
08-D-123519 02-Apr-2016 21:58:54
05-WD-3052  02-Apr-2016 22:06:380
05-WD-3052  02-Apr-2016 22:18:560
08-D-123519 02-Apr-2016 21:58:54
05-WD-3052  02-Apr-2016 22:29:100
08-D-123519 02-Apr-2016 21:58:54
```

and I am and searching for a string and trying to print it out like so

```
fileID = fopen('myfile.txt','r');
tScan = textscan(fileID, '%s','Delimiter','');
tScan = tScan{:};
licenseP = ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(tScan,'05-WD-3052'))
output = [tScan{licenseP}]
```

The output i get is all in one line

```
05-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:03:35005-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:06:38005-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:18:56005-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:29:100
```

but what im trying to get is

```
05-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:03:350
05-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:06:380
05-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:18:560
05-WD-3052 02-Apr-2016 22:29:100
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `output = [tScan{licenseP}]` concatenates all of the strings together. Leave them in a cell array by using parentheses.

Comment: Use `vertcat( tScan{licenseP} )`.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasW. that works perfectly now.

Comment: @MatthiasW. is there anything else i can use instead of vertcat that will give the same result? Its just that if i have a "tab(\t)" in the file. i get the error  `Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: If they are of different length you'll have to keep them in the cell array. Or remove all the tabs.